# Nuances of "I move to speak"?

Tags: nuance

I heard a lawyer say *"I move to speak"* in a sitcom and I wonder what its nuances are.

Searching for the phrase doesn't give many results, so it seems like it's not a common phrase.

Is it only used for taking one's turn to speak? Announcements, etc?

Comment: It's probably a (poor) attempt to mimic "Robert's Rules of Order" and other practices in formal meetings, where a speaker from the "floor" must be recognized by the Chair before speaking.

Answer (score 4):

> move
>   7. To make a formal motion in parliamentary procedure: move for an adjournment.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/move)

"parliamentary procedure" here does not only refer to a legislative parliament, but can include meetings of:

> clubs, organizations, legislative bodies and other deliberative
>   assemblies.
>  [Parliamentary procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_procedure)

A motion is a proposal:

> motion
>   8. Law An application made to a court for an order or a ruling.
>   9. A formal proposal put to the vote under parliamentary procedures.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/motion)

Collins Dictionary says that "to move" in this sense is usually followed by "for":

> 12. (Parliamentary Procedure) (when: tr, often takes a clause as object; when intr, often foll by for) to suggest (a proposal)
>       formally, as in debating or parliamentary procedure
>      [Collins
>       English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/move)

This is the formation of the first example sentence above: "move for an adjournment."

But "to" can also follow "move", as shown by the use of the following:

[Motion to strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_to_strike_(court_of_law))
[Motion to quash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_to_quash)
[Motion to recess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recess_(break)#Parliamentary_procedure)

> You want to take a break  for a while.
>  • After recognition, " Mister
>   Chairman , I move to recess for ten minutes."
>   [Robert's Rules Cheat Sheet](http://diphi.web.unc.edu/files/2016/10/cheat-sheet.pdf)

You haven't given much context of the phrase used in the sitcom, but "I move to speak" sounds like a participant in an assembly/meeting/court is asking permission to speak. A chairman may put the motion to a vote. In other cases, such as in a courtroom, the motion may be granted or denied by a single judge.

Comment: The sentence might be used, in a jocular sense, when someone among a group of people talking is trying to "get a word in edgewise".

Comment: This is the correct answer without brio. It can be used in everyday conversation for: I suggest we do x.

Comment: It may also be intended to reference legal motions and courtroom speech. Of course, the joke is that no one actually makes a motion to speak—regular people just don't talk like that, and even in court or Parliament the procedure to be recognized would never include that phrase, because once you say "I move" you're already speaking.

Comment: @1006a That's true that regular people don't talk like that. But to say it doesn't make sense because you're already speaking isn't quite true. "I move to speak" may be a customary way to ask for permission to make a subsequent longer act of speaking, such as to make an application or an address. You have to be speaking in the first place in order to ask permission to speak further. Also remember that "I move" is to make a motion/proposal. For all I know the exchange might have gone: "Your Honour, I move to speak." Judge: "Granted." Now counsel can address the judge.

Comment: @Zebrafish I have to go to meetings about every week that are run by Robert's Rules, and have a law degree, and I have never heard anyone say "I move to speak". There are official ways to be recognized (get permission to speak) and none of them are that phrase. In meetings you have to be officially recognized before you can even make a motion (generally by standing or raising your hand and waiting for the chair to recognize you), and in court you would usually say something like "Your Honor, may I be heard?" This sounds like someone who *doesn't* speak legalese trying to sound lawyer-ish.

Comment: I should say I've never heard anyone who was comfortable in the milieu say anything like that. People who are unfamiliar with all the formalisms say all kinds of things, like "I *motion*" instead of "I move". That's what this sounds like. I don't know whether the writers were trying to make the lawyer sound ignorant, or whether they were themselves ignorant and trying to make the lawyer sound lawyerly. But either way it's not something anyone should say unless tongue is firmly in cheek.

Comment: @1006a To begin with we don't know the expression the OP gave is supposed to be in conformance with Robert's Rules of Order. About 85 to 95 percent of organizations in the United States use it. Secondly, to say it shouldn't be said by anyone unless it's tongue-in-cheek is simply making a statement that you know all the nuances of parliamentary procedures across all places and jurisdictions. That's very presumptive of you. What I'm saying is that you should consider that there are places where expressions are used correctly, and which you've never heard people say before.